# Creating a function to run according to time of day

Tags: c#, winforms, time, timer

Currently working on something in visual C#. What I have now is an application that takes input from a textbox and when they hit the start button the program will run and grab that info. What I want to do with it is check what time they input and compare it to the current time on the computer and run a function when the clock reaches that time. This is something I'll have running for many weeks at a time. Any idea how I could do this? Or maybe the best way to do it? Will provide more info if needed.

This is what it looks like thus far:
[Current Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u27FQ.png)

I'm not sure if I should be using a standard textbox or something else for this.
Thanks!

EDIT:
OK well, I ended up not creating this program in C# at all. I ended up writing a 1 line batch file that utilized Robocopy (built into Windows) to verify and copy files. Then I used Task Scheduler (also built into Windows) to make sure the batch file is run every day at XX time of day.

Comment: so you want to program an automatic start in the future, where the user can input the starting time? Did I get you right? Any code that shows how far you got yet?

Comment: Use a timer that ticks every however many seconds, every tick it checks the current time, if current time > input time then run the process.

Comment: Maybe create a seperate process that has no window to check the time.

Comment: Updated it a bit with a pic

Comment: @DylanBeck updated my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timer as @Equalsk suggests or use Reactive Extensions (it is a NuGet package,see https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) and do something like this:

```
var dueTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
Observable.Timer(dueTime).Subscribe(time =>
                {
                    // do something
                });
```

Instead of a `TextBox` you should use a `DateTimePicker`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229631(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: omg the date time picker! That's perfect! thank you. Is there a way to condense the datetime picker to just time? The date at which the program is run is unimportant. I just need the time.

Answer (score 0):

if your task should be run at a specific hour and minute (not second), you could write date and time that user entered into xml or database. Then, at the same time, application could check xml/database every minute and if date/time is right, it would execute your method.

Alternatively, you can use `System.Timer` class and when user enters date and time, calculate milliseconds from current time to entered, and start timer. When time elapses, call your method.

Timer class can take `int32.MaxValue` as maximal interval which is around 3 and half weeks

here is an example (very basic one) of timer usage

```
    public Timer MyTimer { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        double ms = datetime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        MyTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = (int)ms;

        MyTimer.Tick += T_Tick;
        MyTimer.Start();

    }

    private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTimer.Stop();
        //call your method here
    }
```